# Не верное отражение букв на кириллице Kivy python

Tags: python, kivy, windows-7

Kivy не верно отображает буквы, при том, что чистый python такими проблемами не выделялся. Использую Windows 7-64, Ide PyCharm, стоит кодировка 8-UTF [image: (не осуждайте)]

Comment: Попробуйте windows-1251

Comment: и вот обсуждение у них на [гитхабе](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4003)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать так. Должно помочь

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF8')
```